# Script to copy specific columns from one sheet to another, but not in the same order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've got this script working, but I was just wondering if someone could explain how to make it more efficient. Right now I'm just repeating code and that's obviously not the right way to do it.

Basically I'm just trying to copy certain columns from one sheet to another. The catch is I don't want all the columns from the source sheet and they are also not in the same order on the destination sheet. For example: Column A on the source sheet goes in Column D on the destination sheet

```
function copy() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myID');
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Inventory'); 
    var range1 = ss.getRange('A2:A');
    var data1 = range1.getValues();
    var range2 = ss.getRange('D2:D');
    var data2 = range2.getValues();
    var range3 = ss.getRange('F2:F');
    var data3 = range3.getValues();
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myID');
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Inventory Report'); 
    ts.getRange(2, 4, data1.length, data1[0].length).setValues(data1);
    ts.getRange(2, 2, data2.length, data2[0].length).setValues(data2);
    ts.getRange(2, 1, data3.length, data3[0].length).setValues(data3);
}
```

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve all data from source sheet using `getDataRange()`.
- Create data for importing to the destination sheet.

  - Here, I used `filter()` and `map()`.
  - `e[5]`, `e[3]` and `e[0]]` is corresponding to `F2:F`, `D2:D` and `A2:A`, respectively.
  - `[e[5], e[3], "", e[0]]` is coresponding to `getRange(2, 1,`, `getRange(2, 2,` and `getRange(2, 4,`, respectively. There is no `getRange(2, 3,`. So I used `""`.
- Import data to the destination sheet.

#### Modified script :

```
function copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myID');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Inventory'); 
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d = data.filter(function(e, i){return i > 0 && e}).map(function(e){return [e[5], e[3], "", e[0]]});
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myID');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Inventory Report');
  ts.getRange(2, 1, d.length, d[0].length).setValues(d);
}
```

#### Rererences :

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If my understanding was wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this and a very great description of what is doing what :)

Comment: @funkedelic_bob Welcome. I'm glad this was useful for you. Thank you, too.